# How to combine R loop result in a dataframe

Tags: r

My current code is like below:

```
for (i in c(1:10)) 
{excess_returns <- i - 2
print(excess_returns
}
```

When I use print(), it prints out each output but how could I merge each output and make them into a data frame.

This is a simplified vision of my question, I got like 23 columns in a dataset and I would like to use each one of each to subtract another one column, and combine all the outputs together to form up a new dataframe

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

To return the output of the loop as a data.frame, we can use @DaveArmstrong's answer.
But we can also use a looping function to achieve the same desired output:

```
lapply(1:10, function(x) x - 2)
```

If we have an actual data.frame, we use the dataframe as argument to `lapply`, as in:

```
my_df <- iris[1:4]

lapply(my_df, \(x) x-2)
```

Or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

my_df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x -2))
```

Comment: Is the last part in this loop? or how to write this completely

Comment: So basically, I have multiple columns and I would like to use each one of them to subtract another single column. The outputs should be multiple lists or whatever. My question is how could I combine them together into a data frame. may not necessarily use loop

Comment: Your issue seems to be much more complex than shown in your question. Please edit your question as to reproduce your issue better

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```r
excess_returns <- rep(NA, 10)
for (i in c(1:10)) {
  excess_returns[i] <- i - 2
}
excess_returns
#>  [1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that in the above, you first initialize the `excess_returns` vector and then fill it in with the for loop.  This is the preferred method, particularly if the real data problem is much larger than this toy example.